# How to terminate infinite execution of command inside script automatically?

Tags: bash, execution, infinite

I have a command inside my bash script that could start infinite execution. And when it will happen I'd like to terminate the proccess of that command and continue script execution.

I've googled and tried to find duplicate answer - no result:(

"myProgram" is a C language simple program inside bash script that prints "*" to "stars.txt" file.
It's compiled with command `gcc myProgram .cpp -o myProgram`.
"myProgram" can start infinite execution and I'd like to terminate it when it happens.

```
...
./myProgram 2>> log.txt > stars.txt
...
```

Please help me with solution or point me to material that will help to get an answer. If you need any additional information, please ask for it, I'll answer as soon as possible:)

Comment: Why don't you deal with that in your program?

Comment: @oguzismail, according to the task I solve, I can't edit code of that program.

Comment: You can use timers and set a timeout value in the shell script. Can you share the snippet of the code where you are calling the c program?

Comment: The smallest part of snippet code is inside question, Thats a nice advice, thank you:) Answer based on your advice was given lower.

Comment: `can start infinite execution and I'd like to terminate it when it happens.` when WHAT happens? What is the exact condition when you want to terminate the program?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `timeout` shell command to exit the command and start executing the next lines in case the command takes more time than the time specified in the timeout value.

```
...
timeout 100 ./myProgram 2>> log.txt > stars.txt
...
```

In the above program your `./myProgram` will exit if it takes more than 100 seconds.

Comment: This answer will help OP to terminate their program if it takes more than 100 s. However, we (very likely, including OP) are not clear about what the terminating condition is. ("can start infinite execution and I'd like to terminate it when it happens.") It could be (1)time as you interpreted, (2)X kb of stdout produced, (3) or any other event. Just adding this comment here because the question is too broad and this answer handles one interpretation of the question correctly.

Comment: this command would work even if the `myProgram` terminates normally within the timeout